# What operating system supports Raspberry pie 3 to install ROS Indigo?

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Or How to install Ubuntu 14.04 on Raspberry Pie 3 so that I can install ROS indigo on it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281617/what-operating-system-supports-raspberry-pie-3-to-install-ros-indigo?/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use Raspbian its good for ROS and rpi

here is the link:-

http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

it will help you m sure about this

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2018-02-02**:
ok let me try this. Thanks

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-03**:
welcome you :)